How can I fit an inline math expression on the same line as the text preceeding it?
\documentclass[a5paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{graphicx}



\begin{document}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{0.3 Spectra of Operators\hfill}
\setcounter{page}{5}
\textit{Proof.}
Clearly if $x-\lambda$ has an inverse in $\mathfrak{B}$ it has an inverse in $\mathfrak{A}$;
thus $\sigma__\mathfrak{A}$$(x)$\subset$\sigma__\mathfrak{B}$$(x)$. 
Suppose that $\thickmuskip=0muy(x-\lambda)y=y(x-\lambda)=1 $ for some $\thickmuskip=0muy\in\mathfrak{A}$.




\end{document}

I am new and trying to learn. My question is this: When I turn this code into a PDF, the last part ($\thickmuskip=0muy\in\mathfrak{A}$) won't fit within the margins, so it continues onto a third line. How can I fit the last part on the second line? Also, my code probably looks rough, so I'd be so happy if someone helps.

Welcome to TeX.SE. A quick hint: To pretty-print a LaTeX code block in the edit window, highlight it and click on the {} "button" in the ribbon above the window.

Since you're trying to learn, I'll offer my advice.

$ does not mean “print a weird symbol”;
whoever taught you about \thickmuskip=0mu was wrong;
if you get errors from the LaTeX run, you should check the code and fix it;
using mathabx together with newtx is typographically unsound.

Regarding point 3, you get
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>
                   _
l.22 thus $\sigma__
                   \mathfrak{A}$$(x)$\subset$\sigma__\mathfrak{B}$$(x)$.
?
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.22 thus $\sigma__\mathfrak{A}$
                                $(x)$\subset$\sigma__\mathfrak{B}$$(x)$.
?
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.22 thus $\sigma__\mathfrak{A}$$(x)$\subset
                                            $\sigma__\mathfrak{B}$$(x)$.
?
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.22 ... $\sigma__\mathfrak{A}$$(x)$\subset$\sigma
                                                  __\mathfrak{B}$$(x)$.
?
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>
                   _
l.22 ...\sigma__\mathfrak{A}$$(x)$\subset$\sigma__
                                                  \mathfrak{B}$$(x)$.
?
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.22 ...frak{A}$$(x)$\subset$\sigma__\mathfrak{B}$
                                                  $(x)$.
?

The first error message points to __ which is always wrong. Let's fix it, by removing the wrong __ which should be _. You still get two errors:
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.29 thus $\sigma_\mathfrak{A}$$(x)$\subset
                                           $\sigma_\mathfrak{B}$$(x)$.
?
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.29 thus $\sigma_\mathfrak{A}$$(x)$\subset$\sigma
                                                  _\mathfrak{B}$$(x)$.
?

TeX stops at \subset, which is a math mode command. Why? Because you've gone outside of math mode. And this brings us to point 1. The whole
$\sigma_\mathfrak{A}$$(x)$\subset$\sigma_\mathfrak{B}$$(x)$

should be a single math formula, namely
$\sigma_{\mathfrak{A}}(x)\subset\sigma_{\mathfrak{B}}(x)$

Note also the braces around the subscripts. Let's fix. Now your code becomes
\textit{Proof.}
Clearly if $x-\lambda$ has an inverse in $\mathfrak{B}$ it has an inverse in $\mathfrak{A}$;
thus $\sigma_{\mathfrak{A}}(x)\subset\sigma_{\mathfrak{B}}(x)$.
Suppose that $\thickmuskip=0muy(x-\lambda)y=y(x-\lambda)=1 $ for some
$\thickmuskip=0muy\in\mathfrak{A}$.

but this typesets as

which is poorly typeset. There must be some space around the relation symbols \subset and =. No excuse.
And this brings us to point 2. Somebody told you a trick for removing the space around relation symbols. As I said, they're wrong: the space is necessary for the reader to make a sense out of the symbols.
Recommended coding
\documentclass[a5paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
%\usepackage{mathabx} % not along with newtx
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Clearly if $x-\lambda$ has an inverse in $\mathfrak{B}$ it has
an inverse in $\mathfrak{A}$; thus
$\sigma_{\mathfrak{A}}(x)\subset\sigma_{\mathfrak{B}}(x)$.
Suppose that $y(x-\lambda)y=y(x-\lambda)=1 $ for some
$y\in\mathfrak{A}$.
\end{proof}

\end{document}


While you're a beginner, the value of \thickmuskip has been selected after pondering it and looking at many good quality typeset math books and articles.
Maybe you'd like to reduce that space, but you should be very careful in avoiding typographic mistakes: if you reduce \thickmuskip you must also reduce \medmuskip and \thinmuskip. Not a beginner's task. And neither a thesis advisor's.

@cfr OK, perhaps “drop in”?

that would be better. it still doesn't make sense in English, but I would guess what you meant to say correctly. 'give my advice' would be better, though. 'drop' just isn't really the right word here. even with 'in' it doesn't work. (but I probably wouldn't comment in that case, because it wouldn't suggest the opposite of the intended meaning.)

@Sebastiano I didn't check, thanks for noting. amsmath and newtxmath are independent of each other.

There are a number of problems with your code.

Don't go into and out of math mode needlessly.

Load newtxtext and newtxmath after most (best: all) other math-related packages.

Don't place two $ symbols next to each other unless you want to either enter or exit display-math mode. Be careful: $$ does not have same meaning as two consecutive $ symbols.

I suggest you load the amsthm package and use its proof environment instead of re-inventing a proof-like environment on your own.

Two consecutive _ ("underscore") characters are almost certainly a mistake.


Is the following close to what you are trying to typeset?

\documentclass[a5paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%%\usepackage{amsfonts} % is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
%\usepackage{mathabx} % are you sure you need this?
\usepackage{amsthm}   % for 'proof' environment
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
%\pagestyle{myheadings}
%\markright{0.3 Spectra of Operators}
%\setcounter{page}{5}

\begin{proof}
Clearly if $x-\lambda$ has an inverse in $\mathfrak{B}$ it 
has an inverse in $\mathfrak{A}$; thus $\sigma_{\mathfrak{A}}(x)
\subset \sigma_{\mathfrak{B}}(x)$. Suppose that $y(x-\lambda)y
=y(x-\lambda)=1$ for some $y\in\mathfrak{A}$.
\end{proof}

\end{document}


Addendum: If you insert a ~ ("tie") symbol between some and $y\in\mathfrak{A}$ in order to suppress a line break at that location within the sentence, I suggest you also load the microtype package. The result of making these two changes is as follows:

Observe that microtype prefers to place the full some~y\in\mathfrak{A}$ expression on the third line rather than cram it onto the second line.

Building off of egreg's answer, if you want to keep the final math expression with the preceding text, the first thing to do is introduce a tie (~) so the space between "some" and the math cannot be a line break:
… for some~$y\in\mathfrak{A}$.

In most cases you would stop there, leaving the paragraph on three lines but looking better.
But suppose you really do want the content to fit on two lines.  You can do this by temporarily reducing the inter-word spacing for the proof.  First, enclose the paragraph you want to adjust in a group ({ … }). Then, within the group but before the content, redefine the spacing with a reduced inter-word spacing (font dimension #2); here I use 60%:
{\spaceskip=0.6\fontdimen2\font plus \fontdimen3\font minus \fontdimen4\font%
…}

This is closer to fitting, but now LaTeX places a line break in the middle of the final math expression.  To prevent that, you can also enclose the math in an \hbox so that it cannot be broken across lines:
… for some~\hbox{$y\in\mathfrak{A}$}.

I will not say the result looks good, but it does accomplish your aim of crowding everything onto two lines:

\documentclass[a5paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
  {\spaceskip=0.6\fontdimen2\font plus \fontdimen3\font minus \fontdimen4\font
  Clearly if $x-\lambda$ has an inverse in $\mathfrak{B}$ it has an inverse in
  $\mathfrak{A}$; thus $\sigma_{\mathfrak{A}}(x)\subset\sigma_{\mathfrak{B}}(x)$.
  Suppose that $y(x-\lambda)y=y(x-\lambda)=1$ for some~\hbox{$y\in\mathfrak{A}$}.}
\end{proof}

\end{document}


I'd not play with \fontdimen: one can use \spaceskip for this purpose.

@egreg Done, I think.

The default value of \spaceskip is 0pt and when it has this value it's not considered for interword spaces, in favor of the font dimensions. Probably I'd set it in a group around the paragraph you want to be specially treated.

@egreg Also done.
